# How to specify where Git LFS files will be stored?

Tags: git, git-lfs

I was just wondering if anyone could clear up some confusion I have about using Git Large File Storage.

When creating your new repository, I know how to track certain files with `git lfs track`, but how do you specify where those files will be stored?

For example, in the project I am working on there are a number of png and wav files.  These are being tracked using `git lfs track`.  The Git LFS website says that they are stored on a remote server, but I cannot find out where that information is in our repository.

In addition, when a second user clones the repo, the project contains only pointers to the LFS objects. How can they find/use the url for the remote where the actual files are stored?

(We are using Bitbucket and a local system git for our repo.)

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted. I checked all the requirements for posting questions and this met all of them.  It was also not posted on the site already...

Comment: your tags are quite bad, bitbucket, atlassian and gitattibutes do no belong here. instead may add something like git-lfs

Comment: @max630 Yes I tried that at first but I suppose when you first create an account you cannot define custom tags. I made do with relevant tags that would draw in people with pertinent information.  So I'm not sure I would necessarily consider that bad.  Unless there was already a git-lfs tag, and I don't believe there was when I asked the question. Thank you though, I'll consider that next time.

Comment: Note: BitBucket Cloud now supports LFS: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38450750/6309

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The Git Lfs website says that they are stored on a remote server, but I cannot find out where that information is in our repository.

They're not stored *in* the repository, at least in a technical sense.  git-lfs adds a second area, the large file storage area, which is a peer of your repository.  The large files are stored there.

I would have expected BitBucket to present this information in a meaningful way on their website.

> In addition, when a second user clones the repo, the project contains only pointers to the LFS objects.

They need to install git-lfs.  That is the program responsible for downloading and uploading the large file content.

Comment: Turns out the large files were never being sent to the second area.  Thank you, this helped a lot.  (Along with searching through the bitbucket settings for awhile.)

Comment: **"git-lfs adds a second area, the large file storage area, which is a peer of your repository"** Finally! An answer that makes sense. Thank you so much. How did you know this? Can you provide a link or series of git commands that prove your answer? I've been looking at git-lfs docs for an hour and _where_ large files are put is conspicuously absent. How are people comfortable not knowing where their files went?

Answer (score 15):

The Git-LFS storage server is specified by the `lfs.url` property, for example:

```
git config lfs.url https://github.com/foo/bar.git/info/lfs
```

The default (when `lfs.url` is unset) is to derive the Git-LFS server URL from the URL of the remote using some heuristics like: `git@github.com:foo/bar.git -> https://github.com/foo/bar.git/info/lfs`

You can view the current server for each remote with:

```
git lfs env | grep Endpoint
```

Note: current git-lfs (2.13.3) supports only HTTP/HTTPS and `file://` endpoint protocols, so you can't push LFS objects to a remote clone over SSH, for example. A workaround is to mount the remote repository over `sshfs` and use `file://`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, by default they are stored at GitHub's servers. You could also setup a server locally (they provide API documentation and what they call "reference server implementation") for that, and specify the server in git configuration

Comment: Other Git hosting providers besides GitHub also support git-lfs, so this answer is factually incorrect. The answer also does not explain where the files are if not in the repos itself. See Edward's answer.