# Bitbucket - push repo with git lfs

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-lfs

When I'm trying to push my files into bitbucket repo (some of them tracked by git LFS, pattern is `*.uasset`), I'm getting this error (I've changed actual credentials with `---`):

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags --set-upstream origin master:master
Pushing to https://---@bitbucket.org/---/---.git

Git LFS: (0 of 241 files) 0 B / 372.25 MB                                      

Post https://bitbucket.org/account/signin/?next=/account/signin/%3Fnext%3D/account/signin/%253Fnext%253D/---/---.git/info/lfs/objects/batch: stopped after 3 redirects
Post https://bitbucket.org/account/signin/?next=/account/signin/%3Fnext%3D/account/signin/%253Fnext%253D/---/---.git/info/lfs/objects/batch: stopped after 3 redirects
Post https://bitbucket.org/account/signin/?next=/account/signin/%3Fnext%3D/account/signin/%253Fnext%253D/---/---.git/info/lfs/objects/batch: stopped after 3 redirects

error: failed to push some refs to 'https://---@bitbucket.org/---/---.git'

Completed with errors, see above.
```

I don't know what's wrong. Can you advice me how to solve this error?

Comment: Does Bitbucket - the source code hosting service- offer LFS as a service? As far as I know they only offer it for their [Bitbucket Server](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/git-large-file-storage-lfs-794364846.html) - a collaboration software that runs on **your infrastructure**.

Comment: On a related note, [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/gitlab-com/#advantages) offers free private repos, unlimited amount of collaborators for them, plus 10GB of total storage (including **git lfs**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for comments. It seems that Bitbucket really doesn't provide LFS as a service, so I'm going to try GitLab.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, BitBucket does provide support for LFS a few months later (July 2016).

See [issue 11204](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/11204/support-git-lfs-extension-bb-12743)

> Today we released Git LFS in Beta, native in Bitbucket Cloud.
>   While LFS support is in Beta, teams up to 5 users get 1 GB of LFS storage and paid team's storage is based on your user tier.
>
> To get started with the Git LFS Beta, you can enable it in 1 click on the repositories you would like to try it out on. Simply head to the ‘Git LFS Beta’ section on the left side bar in the repository settings in Bitbucket Cloud.

For more information on Git LFS, please see [this blog](https://blog.bitbucket.org/2016/07/18/git-large-file-storage-now-in-bitbucket-cloud).

That new option is also visible in SourceTree:

[image: https://blog.bitbucket.org/files/2016/07/Group-2-Copy-1024x741.png]